# What does the vm operation ParallelGCFailedAllocation mean?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I see this vm operation executed many times when printing the safepoint statistics using -XX:PrintSafePointStats. What does it do?

Googling multiple variations of this keyword has given me nothing but bug reports and core dumps.